# Matching IP in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I use this code to match IP

```
$IP =~ /(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})\.(\d{1,3})/;

if ( $1 < 256 && $2 < 256 && $3 < 256 && $4 < 256) {
print "IP matched";
}
```

I don't want to use if loop. Is there a way we can do the checking ( < 256) in regexp only

I know there is another way like

```
/25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01][0-9][0-9]?/
```

Is there a another shortcut way

Comment: And why do you have this strange requirement?

Comment: @Vijay: Just trying. Somebody asked me few days back about the regexp for IP without "if" loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at @ysth answer or you can store matches into array:

```
my @m = grep $_ <256, $IP =~ /([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3})\.([0-9]{1,3})/;

if (@m == 4) {
  print "IP matched";
}
```

Comment: I tried your code on `$IP="۵.۸.߂.୪";` and got a bunch of Argument isn't numeric warnings :)  Don't use \d when you mean [0-9].

Comment: @mpapec : This is the regexp I was loking for. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

```
use Regexp::Common 'net';

if ( $IP =~ /\A$RE{net}{IPv4}\z/ ) {
    print "IP matched\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not pretty, but how about something like
`/^(1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])(\.(1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){3}$/`

Comment: Or, maybe the answer you're looking for is just "no." There's no magic way I know of to test the size of a number in a regex. But as other posters are pointing out, a regex isn't the only way to do this anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I can understand you are asking about a regex for validating IP address? But why don't you try http://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Validate::IP instead of manual approaches?

Answer (score 0):

Embedded code can be used as a condition inside a regex, and certain branches can be made to force backtracking:

```
qr/
  # the string consists of nothing but 4 bytes separated by a period
  \A (?&decimal_byte) (?: [.] (?&decimal_byte) ){3} \z

  (?(DEFINE)
    (?<decimal_byte>
      ([0-9]{1,3}+)  # 1 to 3 digits without backtracking
      (?(?{ $^N <= 0xFF }) | (*FAIL) )  # (?(?{ COND }) YES | NO )
    )
  )
/x
```

The `$^N` refers to the [last closed capture group](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24LAST_SUBMATCH_RESULT). Note that evaluating code inside regexes has security repercussions<sup>1</sup>, and that this technique is not portable to other regex engines like pcre.

---

1. If you blindly interpolate an untrusted regex, it could execute arbitrary code:

   ```
   my $malicious = '(?{ `rm -rf ~` })';

   say "You were pwned" if $foo =~ /something="$malicious"/;
   ```

   Perl saves you from regex security hell by requiring that you `use re qw/eval/` if you want to be responsible for regex security yourself. Note that this is only necessary if the interpolation triggers a new compilation: `my $ok = qr/(?{ say "yes" })/; $foo =~ /$ok/` works just fine.